# How to implement a SearchBar inside a Map

Tags: swift

In the app that I'm building I was able to implement succesfully a map.
The problem is that when I try to implement a bar with the SearchButton the app crashes and the output says: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key searchButton.'"
Here is the MapViewController file.

Thanks for the help...

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapView.userTrackingMode = .follow
        let annotations = LocationsStorage.shared.locations.map { annotationForLocation($0) }
        mapView.addAnnotations(annotations)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(newLocationAdded(_:)), name: .newLocationSaved, object: nil)
    }




    @IBAction func addItemPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let currentLocation = mapView.userLocation.location else {
            return
        }
        LocationsStorage.shared.saveCLLocationToDisk(currentLocation)
    }

    func annotationForLocation(_ location: Location) -> MKAnnotation {
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = location.dateString
        annotation.coordinate = location.coordinates
        return annotation
    }


    @IBAction func searchButton(_ sender: Any)
    {
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        present(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
    {
        //Ignoring user
        UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

        //Activity Indicator
        let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        activityIndicator.style = UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.gray
        activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()

        self.view.addSubview(activityIndicator)

        //Hide search bar
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        //Create the search request
        let searchRequest = MKLocalSearch.Request()
        searchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBar.text

        let activeSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: searchRequest)

        activeSearch.start { (response, error) in

            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

            if response == nil
            {
                print("ERROR")
            }
            else
            {
                //Remove annotations
                let annotations = self.mapView.annotations
                self.mapView.removeAnnotations(annotations)

                //Getting data
                let latitude = response?.boundingRegion.center.latitude
                let longitude = response?.boundingRegion.center.longitude

                //Create annotation
                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.title = searchBar.text
                annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude!, longitude!)
                self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

                //Zooming in on annotation
                let coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude!, longitude!)
                let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1)
                let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
                self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
            }

        }
    }



    @objc func newLocationAdded(_ notification: Notification) {
        guard let location = notification.userInfo?["location"] as? Location else {
            return
        }

        let annotation = annotationForLocation(location)
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
}
```

Comment: you have your output disconnected, check out your storyboard and check that your button it's linked to its corresponding outlets and events

Answer (score 0):

you have your output disconnected, check out your storyboard and check that your button it's linked to its corresponding outlets and events.

In the connections inspector you should be able to see the outlets of the button if it's a bar button item.

[image: photo]

Comment: It's a bar button iteam, where should I link it? To the MKMapView?

Comment: The button it's not linked. It's a search button for a map, how can I link it properly in order to do his job?

Comment: where did you add the button in the storyboard?

Comment: I'v added it in the Navigation Iteam. And under the Navigation Iteam I have the MapView

Comment: do you have your code on some repository to have a look at it?, I think that way will be faster to fix your issue

Comment: No sorry, How can I share the project with you? Discord is ok?

Comment: sure, you can find me as zamuset there

Comment: I need the number afte ryou name... mine is Asdrubale99#5787

Comment: @NicoRizzi mine is zamuset#3678 I couldn't find you

Comment: Ok I'v added you!